# Delete period after title in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I have been given the style reference guide below. I know it's absolute rubbish, but I have to follow it.

[image: Referencing]

I want to remove the period after the end of the title  "located at." Please I don't want to have to touch the Bib file I'm not that good unless given explicit instructions. I'm interested in anyway that can reference a website as described in the image. If the date can be removed from the title in the Bibliography that would be a bonus. Here's my MWE that took me a week to produce. There's one answer on the website, but it's too complicated for me to follow.

```
\documentclass[ a4paper,12pt]{article}
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB



\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}
%% or
% \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder=000}

% hack into hyperref
\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
    \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}}%
    \def\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}%
    \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother


\raggedright

% stops indent of second line in Bibliograph
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}





\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\hypersetup{
    %colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    %urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    %linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = red, %Colour of citations
    }




% This is needed for arial
\usepackage{fontspec}% this is needed for arial
\setmainfont{Arial} % this is need for arial

\usepackage[left=3.25cm,top=3cm,right=3.25cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}




\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MCOSW,
    author = "Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jafri and Ian Millard",
    title = "Managing co-reference on the semantic web",
    journal = "WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)",
    month = "April",
    year = "2009",
}

@book{SPgood,
    title = {A new look at the sacraments},
    author = {Bausch, W. {\relax J}},
    year = 1998,
    publisher = {Twenty Third Publications, Mystic, Connecticut},
    location = {Neverland and Wonderland}
}


@Misc{Tho98w,
    Author = "F Brennan",
    Title  = "\emph{What do our Students Rightly Ask of us, the Church Who Are Many Parts, One Body, \textnormal{ 13 August, 2004, located at}}"   ,

    Note   = " \ULurl{http://www.uniya.org/talks/brennan 13aug04.html},
    [Accessed: 9th December, 2023]",
    year = 1998,
}





\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Just in case I need multiple authors \citep{MCOSW}.
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    This is the correct citation \citep{SPgood}

    \vspace{0.5cm}  
    
    This is a citation from a  website \citep{Tho98w}
    
    

    
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but the bib entry Tho98w is completely wrong, you should not have formatting like \emph in the entry and certainly not have trailing part phrases like `\textnormal{ 13 August, 2004, located at}`   the whole point of a bib file is that the ordering and formatting of the fields is specified by the bib style. that "title" entry is not the title of the work

Comment: Thanks, David, for the quick response. I put the \emph so that the website was italicized. How would your right the bib Tho98w correctly?

Comment: but the _whole point_ of using bibtex is that such style choices are made by the bibliography style. putting emph there is like using `\textbf{Intro}` instead of `\section{Intro}` and then wondering why it doesn't pick up the document class sectioning design,

Comment: So, what bibliography style should I have used, please?

Comment: whatever bib style you want, as for the apalike one you use it italicises book titles see how it generates  `{\em A new look at the sacraments}.` without any font commands messing up the `title` field for that entry.  but for `@misc` it uses less formatting as you are not saying what kind of publication it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really avoid writing a bib file that assumes the fields will be output in a particular order, such as here ending a title field with "located at" and relying on bibtex to put something there. If you need that for some special document it is probably better simply to write the `thebibliography` environment directly and not use bibtex at all.

However having got this far I would simply remove the trailing `.`

change the title entry to

```
    title  = "\emph{What do our Students Rightly Ask of us, the Church Who Are Many Parts, One Body, \textnormal{ 13 August, 2004, located at}}\eatdot"
```

and  before the bibliography in the document add

```
\def\eatdot.{}
    
    \bibliography{\jobname}
```

Then if you regenerate the bib file and run bibtex to generate the bbl it will look like

```
\newblock \emph{What do our Students Rightly Ask of us, the Church Who Are Many
  Parts, One Body, \textnormal{ 13 August, 2004, located at}}\eatdot.
```

where `\eatdot.` produces no output.

Comment: David, this was the first time I have used latex in this way. Can you give me a link, or give me an example for using thebiblography enviroment directly and not us bibtex at all

Comment: look at the .bbl file, basically  bibtex just makes a fancy enumerate list, you can put such a list directly in the document.

Comment: I tried the eatdot, and it didn't work, it only works in the note= field

Comment: oops sorry I did test but copied in wrong version @Jon

Comment: @Jon updated: move it after the `}`

Comment: Just so that someone doesn't waste a lot of time. \def\eatdot.{} \ bibliograph{name} has to go at the very end of  the tex file. It didn't work for me putting  def\eatdot.{} in the preamble.

Comment: @Jon it has to go anywhere before `\bibliography` the preamble is the natural place